# Is 'iconography' as a tag a good idea?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that we get quite a lot of questions about symbols or signs on the site.

Personally, I find these interesting and think they should be grouped under an 'iconography' tag (I added it here [What is the out-of-universe origin of the rebel crest?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184111/what-is-the-out-of-universe-origin-of-the-rebel-crest)) however I don't want to do this if there is not a consensus that this is a good idea (or at least there is not a consensus it is a terrible idea)

Does anyone like this idea, or does anyone strenuously object?

Comment: iconography is like the "hairstyles" and "posters" tags we had for a while. yes, we had some questions about them, but do we really expect to have "iconography" experts, or ones that that are experts in the broad subject across multiple franchises?

Comment: @phantom42 perhaps Robert Langdon, Professor of Symbology, could be persuaded to weigh in?

Answer (score -1):

Per the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/tagging).

> **What are tags, and how should I use them?**
>
> ***As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible***, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if
>   you have sufficient reputation, **you should only create new tags when
>   you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new
>   topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.**

In this case, I'm not seeing a *strong* reason to create and apply this tag other than your personal urge to lump several similar questions together. Note also that "iconography" is [not a common word](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) which means that your new tag is unlikely to be searched for by many users even if they've also got an interest in finding out about science fiction logos and symbols.

---

- **Q. Can you do it if you want to?**

  **A.** *Go for it.*
- **Is it a good idea?**

  **A.** *No, not really.*

Comment: If it were created organically, I would likely have cleaned it up after seeing it created.